# Issue with Docker: "Error response from daemon: failed to create task for container"

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

Hello Stack Overflow community,

I am encountering an issue while trying to set up a development environment using Docker. I've downloaded a repository to my computer, and when attempting to create the Docker environment, I encounter the following error:

```
#18 [celery production-stage  5/25] RUN xargs -a /tmp/apt-requirements.txt apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends && apt-get clean && rm -rf /etc/cron.*/*
#18 1.052 Reading package lists...

#18 2.170 Building dependency tree...

#18 2.324 Reading state information...

#18 2.340 E: Unable to locate package software-properties-common
#18 2.341 E: Unable to locate package aria2
#18 2.341 E: Unable to locate package curl
#18 2.341 E: Unable to locate package openssl
#18 2.341 E: Unable to locate package ca-certificates
#18 2.341 E: Unable to locate package libxml2
#18 2.341 E: Unable to locate package wget
#18 2.341 E: Unable to locate package libsm6
#18 2.341 E: Unable to locate package libxrender1
#18 2.341 E: Unable to locate package libfontconfig1
#18 2.341 E: Unable to locate package git
#18 2.341 E: Unable to locate package sudo
#18 2.341 E: Unable to locate package cron
#18 ERROR: process "/bin/sh -c xargs -a /tmp/apt-requirements.txt apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends && apt-get clean && rm -rf /etc/cron.*/*" did not complete successfully: exit code: 123
------
 > [celery production-stage  5/25] RUN xargs -a /tmp/apt-requirements.txt apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends && apt-get clean && rm -rf /etc/cron.*/*:
2.341 E: Unable to locate package openssl
2.341 E: Unable to locate package ca-certificates
2.341 E: Unable to locate package libxml2
2.341 E: Unable to locate package wget
2.341 E: Unable to locate package libsm6
2.341 E: Unable to locate package libxrender1
2.341 E: Unable to locate package libfontconfig1
2.341 E: Unable to locate package git
2.341 E: Unable to locate package sudo
2.341 E: Unable to locate package cron
------
failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c xargs -a /tmp/apt-requirements.txt apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends && apt-get clean && rm -rf /etc/cron.*/*" did not complete successfully: exit     code: 123
exit status 17
```

Steps to Reproduce:

```
Downloaded the repository to my hard: https://github.com/ijmarshall/robotreviewer/tree/master#docker
Then tried to create Dev Environments
```

But I got the problem I mentioned

Environment:

```
OS: [Win 11]
Docker version: [Docker version 24.0.7, build afdd53b]
```

Please, I am new here I don't even know what does docker mean, but I really want this RobotReview application.
I appreciate any assistance or guidance you can provide in resolving this matter. Thank you!